# Writing to file for a maths quiz error: "io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable"

Tags: python, file-writing

Python Code:

```
#Maths Quiz
#Generate a random number so that your questions are not always the same
#Generate a number and store number

import random #Allows the user to use random selection
import sys #Allows the program to end when finished

def begin():
    print("Hello there! Welcome to the Maths Quiz!")
    menu()


def quiz():
    cor=0 #Correct counter
    n=1 #Counter for question number
    for i in range(0,10): #i is the counter, the range of 0-10 gives 10 questions
        num1 = random.randint(5,10) #First number is a random integer between 5 and 10
        num2 = random.randint(1,5) #The second number is a random integer between 1 and 5
        operator = random.randint(1,4) #The operator is a random number, 1-4 – this is then decided using an if statement 
        if operator == 1:
            total=num1+num2
            answer=int(input("What is {0} + {1}? ".format(num1,num2)))
            n=n+1
        elif operator == 2:
            total=num1-num2
            print("Question",n,":")
            answer=int(input("What is {0} - {1}? ".format(num1,num2)))
            n=n+1
        elif operator == 3:
            total=num1//num2
            #// is used so that the audience of this program can use and understand it
            print("Question",n,":")
            answer=int(input("What is {0} ÷ {1} to the nearest whole number (no remainder) ".format(num1,num2)))
            n=n+1
        elif operator == 4:
            total=num1*num2
            print("Question",n,":")
            answer=int(input("What is {0} x {1}? ".format(num1,num2)))
            n=n+1
        else:
            print("Unable to do this.")

        if answer==total:
            cor=cor+1
            print("Correct \n")
        else:
            print("Incorrect \n")

    print("You scored {0} out of 10".format(cor)) #Prints a total score after the quiz
    percentage = cor*10 #Calculates a percentage
    print("...That is",percentage,"%") #Prints the percentage
    print("Adding to scores list!")
    addScore(percentage)

def addScore(percentage):
    name=input("Enter your name: ")
    f=open("scores.txt")
    f.write(name+"\n")
    f.write(str(percentage)+"%\n")
    f.close()
    main_menu()

    if percentage <= 30: #A statement to decide how well the student has done
        print("You should practice more")
    elif percentage <= 60:
        print("You have a good understanding")
    elif percentage <= 80:
        print("You have a very good understanding")
    elif percentage > 81:
        print("You have an excellent understanding! Well done!")
    menu()

def viewScores():
    f=open("scores.txt","2")
    print("               HIGH SCORES                 ")
    print("===========================================")
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
    print("===========================================")

    f.close()
    menu()


def menu():
    print("===========================================")
    print("           What do you want to do?         ")
    print("===========================================")
    print(" 1.  QUIZ")
    print(" 2.  VIEW SCORES")
    print(" 3.  EXIT")
    print("===========================================")
    opt = int(input())
    if opt == 1:
        quiz()
    elif opt == 2:
        viewScores()
    elif opt == 3:
        print("Goodbye!")
        sys.exit()

begin()
```

Comments are listed using #
At the moment, I'm still getting used to using the writing-to-file technique and used a method from some example code. I used the code from the example logically although these errors occured, I would be very greatful if they could be rectified and explained out.

Thank you :-)

Comment: Open the file writable; `open("scores.txt", "w")`. What do you think the argument `"2"` does when you open the file again?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, from the example code I had I assumed "2" was referring to the input that called the open in the first place.

Comment: In `addScore` you should use `f=open("scores.txt", "w")` while in `viewScores` there should be `f=open("scores.txt", "r")`.